# how to create groups with duplicate keys in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

What I wish to do is create groups based on the last column (key) such that in the first group I get for example the row 1. For the second group I get rows 1 and 2. And in the 3rd group I get the last two rows.

I tried to do it with pandas groupby method, `grouped = df1.groupby('Key')` but as expected it returns only 2 groups.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4'],
   ...:                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
   ...:                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
   ...:                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4'],
                            'Key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K0', 'K0']},
   ...:                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])


df1
Out[89]: 
    A   B   C   D Key
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  K0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  K1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  K1
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  K0
4  A4  B4  C4  D4  K0
```

Comment: So you want to group only by sequential repeated keys?

Comment: A common question .

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`shift`** and **`cumsum`** then **`groupby`**

```
grouped = df.groupby((df.Key != df.Key.shift()).cumsum())
grouped.groups

{1: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64'),
 3: Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')}
```

To show *why* this works:

```
(df.Key != df.Key.shift()).cumsum()

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
Name: Key, dtype: int32
```

Each time `Key` changes, the cumulative sum of the column will increase by one, even if the value has been seen before.  This allows you to groupby this new series, which only groups sequential repeated keys.

Comment: and any way to know which key got repeated? I mean in this case key0 got repeated.

Comment: can attribute a category to each `key` and it would appear after the groupby (e.g. if `agg` by 'first')

Comment: If you interested, added iterators method in the duplicate tag question :-)